Loading table from snowflake dwh into postgreSQL db directly
I'm trying to write a few python scripts that will take tables I have in snowflake and transfer them to a postgreSQL db. I have to convert each row in my snowflake tables into json strings so in postgreSQL the table will just have and index column and a json string that contains the entire row from the snowflake table.
This part I can handle but I am having trouble get my loading times to be small. My current method involves extracting the snwoflake tables into an s3 bucket as csv.gz files using the snowflake COPY command. Then once in s3 i use the psycopg2 library to connect to the postgreSQL db and the copy_expert method with another COPY query to load all the csv files from s3 into a specific table in my postgreSQL db.
The whole process takes me a 2-3 hrs to load around 50-60 GB of data. From googling around I get the impression this can be done much faster and was wondering if I can just connect directly to postgreSQL from snowflake using python and execute some command to copy the data over? Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!
Current method involves using python to execute queries against the snowflake and postgreSQL db. After some manipulation of the table in snowflake I copy it into s3 using:
import os
import psycopg2
import boto3
from connections import SnFlDWH

# copy table from snowflake into s3
query = f"COPY INTO 's3://{bucket_name}/{s3_key}'
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM {db_name}.{schema_name}.{table_name}
)
FILE_FORMAT = (
    TYPE = CSV,
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\"' 
)
OVERWRITE = TRUE
CREDENTIALS = (
    AWS_KEY_ID='{aws_key}',
    AWS_SECRET_KEY='{aws_secret}'
);"

# establish a connection to snowflake and execute the query
snfl_conn = SnFlDWH()
snfl_conn.execqute_sql(query)

# establish a connection to postgreSQL db
pstg_conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host=host,
        database=database,
        user=user,
        password=password
    )

cursor = conn.cursor()

# connect to s3 and get a list of all files on specific s3 bucket
# download each csv.gz file and read the file in locally
# load each csv file into the specified postgreSQL table using the COPY command
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_key=aws_key, aws_secret=aws_secret, region_name=region_name)
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=s3_key)
    for obj in response.get('Contents', []):
        file_name = obj['Key']
        if file_name.endswith('.csv.gz'):
            # Download files from S3
            local_file_name = f"/tmp/{os.path.basename(file_name)}"
            s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, file_name, local_file_name)
            #Load data from local file into Postgres table
            with gzip.open(local_file_name, 'rb') as f:
                cursor.copy_expert(f"COPY {postgres_table_name} FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER ','", f)
            # Clean up: Delete the downloaded file
            os.remove(local_file_name)
            #Delete file from S3
            s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
            
    # Commit the transaction and close the cursor and connection
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()



Accessing a database or other service outside of Snowflake requires using External Network Access. See Connecting to an On-prem Database from within Snowflake for more information with an example of connecting to another database. The example is to an on-premises database, but the process is the same.
